# Excel combinations of multiple sets of items

Tags: excel, combinations, permutation

I'm searching for an easy way to list all possible combinations for three sets of items in excel.

For example, taken the following three sets of items, each item in its own cell:

```
(meals) pizza, pasta, lasagne    
(drinks) wine, beer, water    
(dessert) ice, fruits
```

now I want to list all possible combinations, each in its own row like

```
pizza, wine, ice
pasta, wine, ice
lasagne, wine, ice
pizza, wine, fruits
...
lasagne, water, fruits
```

ordering doesn't matter.

Is there any predefined function for that?

Comment: You would need to write some VBA for this I believe.

Comment: Try [Creating an Excel Matrix](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/creating-an-excel-matrix/d75940ad-973d-4c85-8490-1ad135519baf) for some recursive loops with meal planning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the items to your worksheet in the first three columns like this
    `A       B     C
pizza   wine  ice 
pasta   beer  fruits
lasagne water`

Then, you can get the combinations in F, G, H using the following formulae.

F1:
    `=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),
INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($F$1))/(COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C))+1)),
"")`

G1:
    `=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),
INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1),
"")`

H1:
`=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)+1<=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)*COUNTA(C:C),
INDEX(C:C,MOD(ROW()-ROW($F$1),COUNTA(C:C))+1),
"")`

Pull down the cells until the values are empty.  Then you may want to combine the results to column I with `=IF(F1<>"", F1 & ", " & G1& ", " & H1, "")`