# Matching substrings and counting their occurrences to produce a brief sentence

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, string-matching

I've the following Excel data:

```
     A              B              C
  + ------------   -------------   -----------------
1 | WORD           WORD MIX        MATCH TEXT RESULT
2 | somewordsome   emsomordsowe    ...
3 | anotherword    somethingelse   ...
4 | ...            ...             ...
```

I'd like to:

- Firstly, get an array, say `ArrayOfGroups`, by splitting the string in the `A2` cell in *unique* groups of 2 to 12 *adjacent* chars (note: 2 is the minimum number of chars to form a group; 12 is the total number of the word's chars) i.e. the groups of 2 chars would be `so`, `om`, `me`, `ew`, `wo`, `or`, `rd`, `ds` (note: the last `so`, `om` and `me` groups are excluded because they are repeated); the groups of 3 chars would be `som`, `ome`, `mew`, `ewo`, `wor`, `ord`, `rds`, `dso` (last `som` and `ome` excluded); the groups of 4 chars would be `some`, `omew`, `mewo`, `ewor`, `word`, `ords`, `rdso`, `dsom`; ... and so on until the full string `somewordsome`.
- Then, iterate the above-mentioned `ArrayOfGroups` to check if each of its element is a substring of the `B2` cell and return a new array, say `ArrayOfMatches`, containing all the elements (the characters "group names") that are substrings of `B2` and the number of occurrences found in `B2`.
- Finally, output in the `C2` cell a sentence built using the `ArrayOfMatches` data that says something like this:

  **2 matches for `so`, 1 match for `som` and `rd`**

Probably there are other and better approaches to compute the above sentence that is the final result wanted. Maybe I need to use a User Defined Function... but I never made it.

Is there someone that could give help?

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code.**

Comment: I don't have code (I assume you're referring to VBA code).

Comment: Have a search on here, try “combinations” for a start...

Comment: What is the first *specific* part of the process you're having a problem with?  What have you tired to solve that, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: I *tried* almost everything using the basic functions of Excel, including their combination, and also to search for some UDF scripts without success, starting more than 24 hours ago no stop! :) I

Comment: BTW Why the down vote?!

Comment: @SolarMike Please, show me the way for a combination.

Comment: Start with looking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/12948338/4961700

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/q/32853339/4961700 and this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/27917130/4961700 which should give you a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try something like this

Code edited to avoid counting for same substring found multiple times.

```
Sub test2()
Dim Xstr As String, Ystr As String
Xstr = "somewordsome"
Ystr = "emsomordsowe"
MsgBox Xmatch2(Xstr, Ystr)
End Sub
Function Xmatch2(Xstr As String, Ystr As String) As String
Dim XSubStr As String, YSubStr As String
Dim xLn As Integer, yLn As Integer
Dim XArr As Variant, LnSubStr As Integer
Dim Rslt As String, Cnt As Integer
Dim Xrr() As Variant, Xcnt As Integer, Chk As Boolean
Rslt = "'"

xLn = Len(Xstr)
yLn = Len(Ystr)

    For LnSubStr = 2 To xLn        'length of substring
    Xcnt = 0
    ReDim XArr(1 To 1)
         For Y = 1 To xLn
         XSubStr = ""
         Xcnt = Xcnt + 1
         ReDim Preserve XArr(1 To Xcnt)
         If Y + LnSubStr - 1 <= xLn Then XSubStr = Mid(Xstr, Y, LnSubStr)
         XArr(Xcnt) = XSubStr
            Chk = False
            For i = 1 To Xcnt - 1
                If XArr(i) = XSubStr Then
                Chk = True
                Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If XSubStr <> "" And Chk = False Then
                Cnt = 0
                ReDim Preserve XArr(1 To Xcnt)
                For Z = 1 To yLn
                YSubStr = ""
                If Z + LnSubStr - 1 <= yLn Then YSubStr = Mid(Ystr, Z, LnSubStr)
                If YSubStr = XSubStr Then Cnt = Cnt + 1
                Next
            If Cnt > 0 Then Rslt = Rslt & Cnt & " Matches for " & XSubStr & ","
            End If
         Next
    Next

Debug.Print Rslt
Xmatch2 = Rslt
End Function
```

Comment: BTW The `yLn = Len(Xstr)` should be `yLn = Len(Ystr)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. it was working correctly as in all the test we used strings with equal length. edited .and corrected.